# getElementByTagName v/s getElementByTagNameNS

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces, jaxp

The environment is Java, the scenario is as following

I have an XML file, which I have converted to Document and the namespaceaware was true at the document builder factory level. When I am doing `getElementsByTagName` and I provide a string which is "prefix:elementName", it works fine.

Question: shouldn't this fail? I was under the impression that I will have to use `getElementsByTagNameNS`. I understand that there are pitfalls to `getElementsByTagName` if the prefix were to change.

Also, the second question is, what effect does setting namespaceaware as true/false at the factory level has on the getElements methods. From what I have tested `getElementsByTagName` works fine, the way I have mentioned, in any case.